# jQuery tabs opening in new window?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-web-api

I am just getting started with jQuery tabs- I am hosting this in a Web.API site.  I have created my tabs in my (razor rendered) page like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="WebApiAppOne">ApplicationOne</a></li>
        <li><a href="WebApiAppTwo">ApplicationTwo</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I have the following jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( {
        load: function ( event, ui ) {
            $( ui.panel ).delegate( 'a', 'click', function ( event ) {
                $( ui.panel ).load( this.href );
                event.preventDefault();
            } );
        },
        beforeLoad: function ( event, ui ) {
            ui.jqXHR.error( function () {
                ui.panel.html( "Unable to load tab content" );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

The first tab shows my `WebApiAppOne` content fine- but when I click on the next tab I go directly to `http://localhost/WebApiAppTwo`.  NOT within the tab 2 content area- the tabs are gone.

The goal for me here was to consolidate several web apps that I have on this site in a common landing page, using tabs to allow the user to choose which app they go to.  But I can't seem to get this to work properly.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem- the web.api site calls modernizer-2.5.3.js by default- somehow this was breaking the jQuery's tab functionality.

I'm not sure why, but commenting that call out fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the href attribute and add a custom attribute.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#WebApiAppOne" data-link="WebApiAppOne">ApplicationOne</a></li>
        <li><a href="#WebApiAppTwo" data-link="WebApiAppTwo">ApplicationTwo</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="WebApiAppOne">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
</div>
<div id="WebApiAppTwo">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
</div>
```

And then read the custom attribute using attr and load the panel.

```
 $( ui.panel ).load( $(this).attr("data-link"));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... where is the $( ui.panel ) code supposed to go?  Load?  BeforeLoad?  I tried both, I get empty tab content areas.